# add place search option in search bar in OSClass

Tags: osclass

I'm new for OSClass. This code from `oc-content\themes\modern\inc.search.php`,

```
<form action="<?php echo osc_base_url(true); ?>" method="get" class="search" onsubmit="javascript:return doSearch();">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="search" />
    <fieldset class="main">
        <input type="text" name="sPattern"  id="query" value="<?php echo osc_esc_html( ( osc_search_pattern() != '' ) ? osc_search_pattern() : $sQuery ); ?>" />
        <?php  if ( osc_count_categories() ) { ?>
            <?php osc_categories_select('sCategory', null, __('Select a category', 'modern')); ?>
        <?php  } ?>
        <button type="submit"><?php _e('Search', 'modern'); ?></button>
    </fieldset>
    <div id="search-example"></div>
</form>
```

Here, i need to add one more option to search. That is **Place**, same as **#query**. What can I do?

And where I can make change(s) for good work to this search?

I know following codes,

```
<input type="text" name="sCity"  id="sCity" value="<?php _e('Enter your city here'); ?>" />
```

that's give the result like following,
[image]

But, My requirement is the `sCity` is also same as `sPattern`. See the `value` in both. sPattern shows same result when redirect. but sCity wouldn't. I need that.

Comment: sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
<form action="<?php echo osc_base_url(true); ?>" method="get" class="search" onsubmit="javascript:return doSearch();">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="search" />
    <fieldset class="main">
        <input type="text" name="sPattern"  id="query" value="<?php echo osc_esc_html( ( osc_search_pattern() != '' ) ? osc_search_pattern() : $sQuery ); ?>" />
        <input type="text" name="sCity"  id="sCity" value="<?php _e('Enter your city here'); ?>" />
        <?php  if ( osc_count_categories() ) { ?>
            <?php osc_categories_select('sCategory', null, __('Select a category', 'modern')); ?>
        <?php  } ?>
        <button type="submit"><?php _e('Search', 'modern'); ?></button>
    </fieldset>
    <div id="search-example"></div>
</form>
```

Also, change sCity to sRegion if you prefer to seach by region and not by city

Answer (score 1):

For Selectable city field

```
    <?php $aCities = City::newInstance()->listAll(); ?>
<?php if(count($aCities) > 0 ) { ?>
<select name="sCity" id="sCity">
<option value=""><?php _e('Select a city...')?></option>
    <?php foreach($aCities as $city) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $city['s_name'] ; ?>"><?php echo $city['s_name'] ; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
<?php } ?>
```